# Question about position size in pinescript 2

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Thank you for your reply in my previous post. I can manage to apply my risk management model into the system and have a lot of idea popping up in my head.

Can we add profit and loss into the capital in TradingView pinescript?

For example..
Capital = 100$
Win 10$ from this trade

The capital is now 110$
and use this capital to calculate next trading position size.

Do we have any way to track profit and loss in the previous trade and apply to next trading position size?

Also I want to add on/off to my trading system filter, could you guide me,please?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.closedtrades.profit` returns you the profit/loss of the closed trades. And `strategy.closedtrades` returns the number of trades.

So if you pass `strategy.closedtrades - 1` into `strategy.closedtrades.profit`, it would return the profit/loss of the last trade.

> Also I want to add on/off to my trading system filter, could you guide
> me,please?

You can have a boolean input and use it as a condition in your calculations.

Something like:

```
en = input.bool(true, "Enable")

if (en)
    // Calculate your filter here
```